# Can you override the NODE_ENV env variable in create-react-app@3.x?

Tags: environment-variables, create-react-app

I'd like to manually change the value of the `NODE_ENV` environment variable when I build my React app in development node (`yarn run start`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, as per create-react-app@3.4.1 at least, this is not possible. Excerpt from the [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/):

> There is also a built-in environment variable called `NODE_ENV`. You can read it from `process.env.NODE_ENV`. When you run `npm start`, it is always equal to 'development', when you run `npm test` it is always equal to 'test', and when you run `npm run build` to make a production bundle, it is always equal to 'production'. **You cannot override NODE_ENV manually**. This prevents developers from accidentally deploying a slow development build to production.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunate that it is so.

I have set different URL-s for different stages as seen below. If I build a production ready enviroment and want to use "test" urls which point to another location, then i should be able to do it. In a ense prod and test enviroments are both done using `yarn run build`, but using the TEST variable I change what URL-s I want. Ofcourse there are other ways to achieve this, but now I have to rethink all of this logic.

```
  const prod = {
    url: {
      API_URL: "https://prod.example.com/api/v1",
      UTILS_URL: "http://prod.example.com/utils"                                                                                                                                                                   
    }
  }
  
  const test = {
    url: {
      API_URL: "https://test.example.com/api/v1",
      UTILS_URL: "http:/test.example.com/utils"
    }
  }
      
  const dev = {
    url: {
      API_URL: "http://localhost:5000/api/v1",
      UTILS_URL: "http://localhost:5000/utils"
    }
  }
          
export const config = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? dev : (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test' ? test : prod));
```

EDIT:

I guess I totally misunderstood this usage of NODE_ENV.

I wish to use these as three different parts:

1. dev for local computer development
2. test for a test environment (and where the test suite does not run)
3. production

As far as I understand testing enviornment tries to run the test suite, which I am not interested in, I just which to create a production static build with different URL-s.